# centos 7 normal user modify the network settings like changing the ipaddress

Tags: networking, centos7, user-settings

In all version Centos 7 normal user can able modify the network settings like changing the ipaddress ... But in centos 6 normal user not able to change the network settings ..

I have changed the user shell also but still same output